# Old slang words for a kiss--cherry smashes and honey cooler--why?

Tags: expressions, idioms, slang

Cherry smashes are defined as feeble kisses and a honey cooler is simply a kiss. Cherry smashes was slang from the 1920s and a honey cooler was slang from the 1930s. Any ideas why feeble kisses would be cherry smashes or why a honey cooler would be a kiss?

Comment: The term is very rare, but it's been used in several ways over the years. 1887: [He's a worker — what they call out West a " honey cooler" or a " rustler."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22honey+cooler+or+a+rustler%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) 1895: [Ain't the Judge a honey cooler, though 1 He ain't the kind that'll hang a man first and try him later](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Judge+a+honey+cooler%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Etc., etc. Also a sensual potential sex partner, which probably leads to the "sexually promising" nuance in OP's also-rare long-lost slang.

Answer (score 3):

Because your gal's lips are red like cherries and her kisses are sweet as honey.

Just don't tell her you had to go to the internet to find this out.